# Comparing tables in lua, where keys are tables

Tags: lua

I need to compare to see if two tables are equal - as in the same content. Both tables have tables as keys.

For example:

```
t1 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
t2 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
t3 = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}
```

t1 and t2 should be equal, but t1 and t3 should not be equal.

Comment: The keys in these tables are not tables.

Comment: What question do you have while programming this? Show your approach.

Comment: it will be very complicated if the key and the value can be any stuct.i suppose you can designe a struct by you own data.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not absolute (does not like keys), but should work with nested tables that you question presents. My concept is recursive and simple:

Take an entry from each input, ensure that they: match in type, both are tables, and both tables are the same length. If these three things are true, you can now 1:1 compare the two tables recursively. If either the types do not match or the tables are a different length, then that is an automatic fail.

```
function compare (one, two)

    if type(one) == type(two) then
        if type(one) == "table" then
            if #one == #two then

                -- If both types are the same, both are tables and 
                -- the tables are the same size, recurse through each
                -- table entry.
                for loop=1, #one do
                    if compare (one[loop], two[loop]) == false then
                        return false
                    end
                end 

                -- All table contents match
                return true
            end
        else
            -- Values are not tables but matching types. Compare
            -- them and return if they match
            return one == two
        end
    end
    return false
end

do
    t1 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
    t2 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
    t3 = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}

    print (string.format(
        "t1 == t2 : %s", 
        tostring(compare (t1,t2))))

    print (string.format(
        "t1 == t3 : %s", 
        tostring(compare (t1,t3))))
end
```

The output is:

```
t1 == t2 : true
t1 == t3 : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to serialize both tables in the manner [shown in Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.2.html).  This will generate an output of a collection of strings that, when run, would re-create the table.  Store the outputs of the serializer in a table rather than outputting them to compare them.

Once both tables are serialized to a collection of strings, it would be simple to compare all lines in serialized table A to all lines in serialized table B and remove any duplicates between them.  If at the end of processing table A there are any lines left in table A or table B then they are not equal.

Code to serialize to table of strings (modified from PIL) and compare two tables a and b:

```
function basicSerialize (o)
    if type(o) == "number" then
      return tostring(o)
    else   -- assume it is a string
      return string.format("%q", o)
    end
end

function save (name, value, saved, output)
    saved = saved or {}       -- initial value
    output = output or {}     -- initial value
    if type(value) == "number" or type(value) == "string" then
        table.insert (output, name .. " = " .. basicSerialize(value))
    elseif type(value) == "table" then
        if saved[value] then    -- value already saved?
            table.insert (output, name .. " = " .. saved[value])  -- use its previous name
        else
            saved [value] = name   -- save name for next time
            table.insert (output, name .. " = {}")     -- create a new table
            for k,v in pairs(value) do      -- save its fields
                local fieldname = string.format("%s[%s]", name, basicSerialize(k))
                save (fieldname, v, saved, output)
            end
        end
    else
        error("cannot save a " .. type(value))
    end
    return output
end

function compareSerializedTable (t1, t2)
    if (#t1 ~= #t2) then
        return false
    end

    for i = #t1, 1, -1 do
        local line = t1 [i]
        for k, comp in ipairs (t2) do
            if (line == comp) then
                table.remove (t1, i)
                table.remove (t2, k)
                break
            end
        end
    end

    return (#t1 == 0 and #t2 == 0)
end

t1 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
t2 = {{1,1},{2,2}}
t3 = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}

o1 = save ('t', t1)
o2 = save ('t', t2)
o3 = save ('t', t3)

print (compareSerializedTable (o1, o2)) --true
print (compareSerializedTable (o1, o3)) --false
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a table comparaison. This is not a builtin function of the language since it has many differents implementation.

A common one is to deeply compare.
The following function will deeply compare tables, it have a third parameter to ignore meta tables or not.

```lua
function deepcompare(t1, t2, ignore_mt)
    local ty1 = type(t1)
    local ty2 = type(t2)
    if ty1 ~= ty2 then
        return false
    end
    -- non-table types can be directly compared
    if ty1 ~= "table" and ty2 ~= "table" then
        return t1 == t2
    end
    -- as well as tables which have the metamethod __eq
    local mt = getmetatable(t1)
    if not ignore_mt and mt and mt.__eq then
        return t1 == t2
    end
    for k1, v1 in pairs(t1) do
        local v2 = t2[k1]
        if v2 == nil or not deepcompare(v1, v2) then
            return false
        end
    end
    for k2, v2 in pairs(t2) do
        local v1 = t1[k2]
        if v1 == nil or not deepcompare(v1, v2) then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

For more informations see: https://web.archive.org/web/20131225070434/http://snippets.luacode.org/snippets/Deep_Comparison_of_Two_Values_3